# Intel RealSense face recognition module in java

Tags: java, realsense

I am working in a research team with the SDK 2016 R1    Intel_rs_sdk_offline_package_r6_8.0.24.6528
Face recognition module and F200 camera.

I am trying to run a basic java (jdk 8u60 , Eclipse 4.4(Luna)) application for one face recognition from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/code-sample-facial-recognition-using-intel-realsense-sdk#comment-1869168)  but it is not working. The configuration code of the module is performed as the documentation says:

```
PXCMFaceData.Face face = faceData.QueryFaceByIndex(0);
PXCMFaceData.DetectionData faceDetectionData = face.QueryDetection();
recognitionData = face.QueryRecognition();
recognitionData.RegisterUser();
PXCMFaceData.RecognitionModuleData recognitionModuleData = faceData.QueryRecognitionModule();
...
```

The code example also uses the face detection module that is working perfectly. I am debugging line by line and I detect an unusual behavior in the following line:

```
int nBytes = recognitionModuleData.QueryDatabaseSize();  ...
```

Where `nBytes` is always `0`.

Can someone confirm if the Face Recognition module is not yet fully functional in java?

best regards

Comment: As you insist in asking a negative question, the answer is: **Yes** :-p And the "best regards" is against the norms of the site, check the FAQs.

Answer (score -1):

Try https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/realsense/camera-sdk/v1.1/documentation/html/doc_face_face_recognition_data.html?cachehash=1791550702 explains /provides Java sample code under the java tab. And additional pages on the online help.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12089844)

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with answering a question - answers are time dependent just like questions. Better to have an answer in hand at the time of the question than have no answer because it might not be available (or relevant) a year from now.